# Grouping a large array of hashes by date ranges

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a large array (~5MB) of hashes that I need to group by rolling date ranges.

Here's the Ruby method that converts the array in to the set of rolling data I'm looking for:

```
def rolling(options = {})
  rolling_items = []

  options[:date_range].each do |day|
    start_date = rolling_start_date(day)
    end_date = day

    range = start_date..end_date

    new_items = options[:data].select{|key, value| range.cover? Date.parse(key[:created].to_s)}.uniq { |h| h[:customer] }

    amount = new_items.count


    rolling_items.push({created: day, amount: amount})
  end

  rolling_items
end
```

That calls a `rolling_start_date` method, which takes a given day and spits out what it's starting date would be:

```
def rolling_start_date(end_date)
  old = Time.utc(end_date.year, end_date.month, end_date.day)
  previous = old - 1.month

  if old.day > previous.day
     start_date = previous + 1.day
  else
     start_date = old - 1.month + 1.day
  end

  start_date.to_date
end
```

I'd call that `rolling` method with: `rolling(date_range: Date.current.beginning_of_day-1.year..Date.current.end_of_day, data: customers)`

**And here's a [gist of the huge array](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Shpigford/2f7e895b81fedf96f1db/raw/d6d4c743c65c3261c201f3cad50f0577f6de7d4d/customers.rb) of customers. Which is used for `data` in the call above.**

So that `rolling` method then loops through each individual day in the overall `date_range` and finds its `rolling_start_date` and then, in this case, finds the hashes in that new date range and counts up the unique customers and pushes it to a new `rolling_items` array so I end up with an array that looks like this:

```
[
   {:created=>Fri, 21 Feb 2014, :amount=>2711}, 
   {:created=>Sat, 22 Feb 2014, :amount=>2716}, 
   {:created=>Sun, 23 Feb 2014, :amount=>2720}, 
   {:created=>Mon, 24 Feb 2014, :amount=>2731}, 
   {:created=>Tue, 25 Feb 2014, :amount=>2746}, 
   {:created=>Wed, 26 Feb 2014, :amount=>2761}, 
   {:created=>Thu, 27 Feb 2014, :amount=>2765}, 
   {:created=>Fri, 28 Feb 2014, :amount=>2754}, 
   ...
]
```

...where each hash is the total number of unique customers for the date range.

So what I need to figure out how to do is still get the unique customer count for each rolling date range without looping over the 5MB array 365 times.

Comment: Interesting and well-stated question.  Perhaps you could break the line `new_items = options...` to avoid the need for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Am I correct in my understanding that `{:created=>Fri, 21 Feb 2014, :amount=>2711},` means you added 2711 customers in the previous month or so?  If that's the case, how about having each hash instead be the total number of customers as at that date, then just compute differences as needed to get the rolling values?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am not understanding the purpose, but could you not iterate the `customers` Array just once, and determine per customer the range of days it would be counted for? If I understand properly, this range is always a month, so I can simply say that customer X which has a plan created on 1 February 2013 will be adding 1 unique customer to all days between 1 February and 28 February, right? That is, every customer simply "generates" +1 for all those days, given we did not already count him (unique customers). Again, perhaps I do not get you properly, but if it's true what I just said you could just do something like:

```
rolling_items = {}

customers.each do |customer|
  start_date = Date.parse(customer[:created])
  end_date = start_date + 30
  (start_date..end_date).each do |date|
    # Add empty Hash with default value 0 if date was not yet in Hash.
    # Add 1 for the customer, so we can see duplicates if we want
    (rolling_items[date] ||= Hash.new(0))[customer[:customer]] += 1
  end
end

rolling_items.each do |date, customers|
  uniq_customers = customers.keys.size # Hash keys are already unique, just count
  puts "\n%s => %s unique customers" % [date.strftime, uniq_customers]
  puts "-" * 20
  customers.each do |customer, times|
    puts "%s => %d" % [customer, times]
  end
end

# 2013-02-28 => 7 unique customers
# --------------------
# cus_05eOKvdnc3MkJO => 2
# cus_0e7LBxIfqSyLAP => 2
# cus_05HVTILpv7CuVS => 2
# cus_1CD4BnX3jDcA3g => 2
# cus_0G9GwU25yAT0ih => 1
# cus_1BqrfANA13SoNc => 3
# cus_0S12vFMb8r6ef1 => 2

# 2013-03-01 ... etc
```

By the way there were a lot of duplicate customer entries with the same dates in there, I'm not sure if that's intended. I took the first 14 items of your giant Array.